# how to kill a GMS mapview on a button click

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am stuck in googlemap integration. I am working with google map actually i want to kill a map view on button click as it is consuming too much memory how it can be kill? i just want to unload a map in my app. below is my sample code but it is not working..

```
 (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [super menuButtonPressed:sender];
    self.mapView_=nil;
}
```

but not working kindly help me regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

All that you code does is remove the local reference to the map view. As the map is still visible in your view, it won't be released as the view will be holding a strong reference.

Try

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [super menuButtonPressed:sender];
    [self.mapView_ removeFromSuperview];
    self.mapView_=nil;
}
```

Comment: but still no difference in memory.. and map view is still present

Comment: Are you sure that self.mapView_ is the actual map that is visible?  If removefromSuperview doesn't remove it, I mould say that it isn't.

Comment: It can't be if removeFromSuperview doesn't remove it. Ether that or this method isn't executing - set a breakpoint to see if it is being called

Comment: when it is removing from superview it only removes marker on map or nothing else...